# Does the equation $y = x\log x$ have a solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the function: $y = x\log x$

Now, put $y = 1$:

so, 
\begin{align*} 
x\log x & = 1\\  
\log x^x & = 1
\end{align*}

Now, this clearly gives a contradiction to the mathematical properties, for demonstration, assume that the base of log here is $2$, i.e. $\log = \log_2$.

So, our equation is:

$$\log x^x = \log_2 2$$

For both sides to be equal, the only thing that will make the equations true is when $1 = 2$, which is impossible.

EDIT TO EXPLAIN HOW 1 = 2:
so we reach a point where
 $$\log_2x^x = \log_2 2$$

This suggests that **x<sup>x</sup>** must be equal to 2, meaning that the base and power must be equal, and the powers are equal when and only when **1 = 2.**
 Where am I making a mistake in understanding?

Comment: If you exponentiate both sides, you get $x^x=2$, not $1=2.$

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: How do u get 1=2?

Comment: @KentaS, I've edited my post

Comment: Would you come to the same conclusion with $x^x=4$? This obviously has a solution $x=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log_2 x^x = \log_2 2$

So far so good. By the one-to-one nature of the logarithm function, you can conclude:

$x^x = 2$.

But I fail to see how you conclude that $1=2$?

*Edited to attempt to answer the clarified post*

$x^x = 2$ does not imply that $1=2$

$x^x = 2$ cannot be solved exactly through elementary means (without invoking special functions such as the Lambert W). However, it can quite easily be solved numerically to give an approximate solution of $x \approx 1.5596$.

Comment: let me explain, I'll edit my post.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: I see my flaw, thanks!